# html content not coming in a straight line

Tags: html, css

[image]

I am designing a web page. In it I am having nested div. And in the centre there is a image and a link.On the inner div I have added onclick event .from which I am calling javascript function and then navigating to the location.

My problem is the links are not coming in straight line.they are been shifted. I want them to come in a straight line.In the image there only two link but there are actually around 16-17 links..I want it to run on IE-6 and onwards but mainly it should run on IE6.

My code snippets are

```
<div id="dashboardOuterDiv"> <div id="dashboardInnerDiv"><div class="dashboardMainInnerDiv" onclick="checkKeyPress1(1)">
     <table width="100%">
    <tr onclick="checkKeyPress1(1)">
    <td class="box">
            <a class="achortable">1</a>
    </td>
    <td >
        <a class="achortable">  
                <span>This is my first link </span>
        </a>
    </td>
    </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
     <div class="dashboardMainInnerDiv" onclick="checkKeyPress1(2)">
     <table width="100%">
        <tr onclick="checkKeyPress1(2)">
        <td class="box">
                    <a class="achortable">2</a>
        </td>
        <td>
            <a class="achortable">
                        <span>This is my second link</span>
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The css code is

```css
#dashboardOuterDiv {width: 100%;
text-align:center;
background-color: #C0C0C0;
position:absolute;
}
#dashboardInnerDiv {
height:90%;
width:90%;
margin-top:0px;
margin-bottom:15px;
background-color:#F2F2F2;
display: inline-block;
text-align: center;
}
.dashboardMainInnerDiv
{
width:90%;
margin-top:15px;
margin-bottom:15px;
background-color:white;
display: inline-block;
text-align: left;
}
.dashboardMainInnerDiv a span
{
padding-left:10%;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:middle;
}
.dashboardMainInnerDiv a img
{
border:0;
vertical-align:middle;
width:20%;
height:12%;
}
.box{
background: url("../images/box.gif") no-repeat scroll 0 0       transparent; /*#008DFF ;*/
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
height: 20px;
padding: 14px 0;
text-align: center;
width: 49px;
float:left;
color:#34BEF5;

 }
```

the images are
[image]
I want it to be some thing like this
[image]

Comment: what you mean by straight line ? would you add screen of how you need the page to be?

Comment: Hi Omar...by straight line I mean the text 'This is first link' and the another text 'This is second link' in the image they are not exactly starting from the the same point.the text are shifted.The first one is more to the right as compared to the second. I want them to be correctly align.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set the width of the first **td** to be 10% or what ever, and add class to the second **td** and set the width of it to be 90% or the remaining percentage of 100% . also set the text alignment of the second **td**

Comment: Hey Omar...thanks a lot ...this solution is working fine...I think I had tried to set align left but setting width was important...+1 for you and once again thank you..:)

Answer (score 1):

Have you closed those two div :   ?

And why do you want to nest those div in the first place ? And to use so much table ? Table is to presenting lots of data, not to do your page layout.

In your case I would use a single "ul" tag (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp) with one "li" tag by line and use css on "span" and "a" to achieve the same design with far less code.

Please note that you can have an "id" attribute on any element, not only "div". This can save you a lot of nesting elements.

Comment: I have closed the divs.Benoit I am using table because my page will be accessed from from both the computer and handheld device.So table is allowing me to adjust the content on its own. Earlier I had tried without table but I was facing number of problems like the image and link were not coming in same line. And as my link size is big at some cases the I was finding it difficult to align it on handheld device.